# How to remount without showexec

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I got elf executables on a USB-stick with a FAT filesystem, by default it’s mounted with the `showexec` option, which seems to prevent me from running these files.

How can I remount the partition without that option?

I tried the following with `-showexec`, `showexec=0`, `showexec=false` to no avail.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mountpoint -o remount,-showexec
```

Comment: Just unmount and mount again without that option?

Comment: `sudo mount -o remount,exec /dev/sdb1 /media/mountpoint`. The `exec` option "`Permit execution of binaries.`". `showexec` is "`Not set by default`". See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: @waltinator, Can you please elaborate on your comment or make a more extensive answer below? I assume that /dev/sdb1 is the already mounted directory of the usb? and /media/mountpoint the new new directory? must a new directory be made beforehand or any preparation or context of this command being run?